# What is acceptable error in prediction models?

Tags: regression

I have developed a model for construction waste reduction, but I'm not sure how to validate it to serve the purpose. I have two sets of data: measured waste % from sites and predicted values obtained from model constructed. How do I tell that the model constructed is good for prediction purposes? The data is linearly related.

Comment: This depends entirely on *your* objectives: why are you predicting? What are you going to do with the predictions later on? What's the cost of being wrong? How precise do you *need* the predictions to be to make use of them at all? ...

Comment: Thanks Marc, the purpose is to be able to predict future waste generation on similar projects as one studied and materials observes.the precision is what im asking, what should be acceptable difference between actual and predicted values?thanks.Lawrence

Answer (score 2):

@Marc is right. The acceptable precision (and total error) depends on your application - it doesn't have anything to do with the modeling.

- If this is an industrial or close-to-industry project these needs should be in the specifications.
- As an alternative, look into the relevant literature about your application.